# Is there a way to adjust the size of the text when reading PDF files?

Tags: pdf, ebook-reader, reading

When I use Aldiko to a book in *epub* format on a mobile device with a small screen, I can read it without problems. The text is adjustable to the size, the application has no issues.

The opposite is true when I'm reading *pdf* file. It's always a fight. The text is small and unadjustable and the application freezes.

Is there a way to adjust the size of the text in my PDF files so that they are more easily readable? I don't intend to read scanned pdfs (this would be even bigger fight). I would like to be able to adjust text size, do scaling and not have the application freeze. I'm open to trying other readers if Aldiko cannot handle this.

EDIT: The title was changed, but note that it's not only the change in the size of text. The text should be flexible to various sizes of devices. This is called floating text (or layout) in HTML terminology. A lot of PDF readers can change the text size without the text fitting the device screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [ezPDF Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader) and use its text column locking feature in landscape orientation (to kick out blank margins and use large device height as width of PDF). I find it useful on my 4.0-inch screen even for the codes because it doesn't change formatting to reflow text. But, if your screen size is much smaller than my one, it'd be useless to you.

Plus, it features voice reading. You can use that too.

Comment: Anyway, `text reflow` is the keyword to solution here. TY :-)

Answer (score 5):

[qPDF Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qoppa.activities.viewer) - a free ad-free Android PDF Reader - also has a great text reflow mode. Users can zoom in and out to increase or decrease the font size. Look for "Reflow Text" under the action toolbar "View" menu.

Comment: qPDF text reflow messes text up for me (for some reason it takes bit of text from a paragraph and displays them at the end of the paragraph). Foxit Mobile PDF seems to work ok.

Answer (score 3):

The best option is [Foxit Mobile PDF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxit.mobile.pdf.lite).

Comment: Does it have Text Reflow function?

Comment: Yes it does and that feature in Foxit works better than in qPDF for me (check my comment under Lilou's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Xodo PDF Reader is a good option, text reflow works really well.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader

Answer (score 1):

You can use [K2pdfopt](http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/) to convert the pdf to your screen size.
Or if you are using an Android device, try [KOReader](http://miscool.blogspot.com/2015/01/koreader-turn-your-android-phone-and.html), which has the most advanced support for dynamic pdf reflow.